# How can I dynamically process all .html files through the Catalyst Framework?

Tags: perl, catalyst, template-toolkit

I want to use Catalyst to process all requests: Both html (mixed with Template Toolkit), and those normally intended to be processed by Catalyst. I am aware of Catalyst::Plugin::Static::Simple, but that doesn't seem like it does what I am describing since it simply prints files statically.

As an example, I want to show whether the user is logged in on index.html without using ajax or SSI. There are many other cases beside that one.

There is probably a simple answer to this...

Comment: If you are showing whether the user is logged in, doesn't that make it a dynamic page?

Comment: Yes, that's true, huh? I'll change my original description.

Comment: Would I just have an auto sub in Root.pm that checks to see if the end of the url is *.html, check to see if the file exists, and then set it as $c->stash->{template}?

Comment: More or less. Exactly the logic you just said, but in a default handler, so it can be properly dispatched by Catalyst. You may find this doesn't scale well if you have a big directory tree of HTML that you're mixing with a lot of Catalyst Controllers. But if they're all in one directory, then it's quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the pointer, RET. My solution turned out to be pretty simple.

I made the nginx config point to my Catalyst App before serving files directly and added the path to my html files to the TT config in myapp.pm.

Here are the basics of the snippet I added to my Root.pm controller in the default subroutine:

```
if($c->req->path =~ m{\.html$} || $c->req->path =~ m{\.htm$}) {
    $c->stash->{template} = $c->req->path;
    $c->detach;
}
elsif($c->req->path !~ m{[.]+}) {
    $c->stash->{template} = $c->req->path . '/index.html';
    $c->detach;

}
```